# Can a react component/library be used in native mobile application

Tags: reactjs, mobile-application

The requirement here is create a react component and this can be reused by other react application by including the dependency in node module. However is it possible for use the same component into any mobile application. 
Have searched a lot but every search directs towards react native. 
My component will be just a simple react component

eg. A => new component just rendering a button.

B is another react app can use A easily. 
Question is : Can A be used/include inside a iOS or Android application.

Comment: Yes, if you wrap it in WebView. But this is bad idea.

Comment: So is it better to host and then use in mobile app,

Comment: some how the requirement is create a react component/ library and reuse across multiple react apps as well as mobile app.